# Вызов класса из любого активити

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Написал отдельный класс, который будет вызываться из любого активити для того чтобы выходить из приложения через алертдиалог. Что передать билдеру?

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    CancelClass cancelClass = new CancelClass();
    cancelClass.onCreateDialog(??);
}
```

---

```
public class CancelClass extends Application {

public void onCreateDialog (??) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(??);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Кстати, вызывать этот класс должен через onBackPressed, то есть системная кнопка назад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего билдер требует контекста. Т.е. в аргументе метода должно быть `Context context` и `context` в билдер передать. Ну а при вызове из активити надо передавать `this`, т.к. активити реализует контекст